# jQuery: Object #<Document> has no method 'find'

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to fetch a response xml from backend and parse it on page with the help of jQuery. 
Code is very simple:

```
var response = "<Response><SomeElement><FewMoreElement></FewMoreElement><FewMoreElement></FewMoreElement><FewMoreElement></FewMoreElement></SomeElement></Response>";
$.parseXML(response).find("someElement").each(function(searchResp){
//Do something
        });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ - "Returns: `XMLDocument`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make it a jQuery object :

Change

```
$.parseXML(response).find("someElement")
```

to

```
$($.parseXML(response)).find("someElement")
```